# Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found

Tags: php, memcached

This is the result I got in my system.

```
php -m | grep -i memcache

memcache
```

Still I get the error "Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found ..." While running a symfony app on apache.

Please help

Comment: Apache and CLI sometimes have different php.ini files, especially on debian/ubuntu distros, IIRC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the apache module memcache.so in your php.ini file:
extension=memcache.so

Comment: And restart apache afterward as well.